# comparing to strings in JavaScript with one from css content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a conditional statement based on a string comparison from a css content attribute.

Here is my code so far but even thought the strings are the same the comparison returns false.

CSS

```
.right-section::before {
        content:" the blue dog";
     /*   position: relative; */
        top: -50px; 
        }
```

Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var content = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.right-section'), ':before').getPropertyValue('content');
         var content2 = " the blue dog";
        if( content == content2) {
           console.log("CSS  running");
            $("#margin-adjust").css("margin-top", "10px !important");
          } 
            });
```

And here is a link to a codepen
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EXZrwB?editors=1111

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSS property value includes the double quotes, so you'd need to compare with a string value that also has them:

```
 var content2 = '" the blue dog"';
```

... then they will be equal.

Comment: You rock!! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The strings aren't the same though...

`content` evaluates to `" the blue dog"`
`content2` evaluates to `the blue dog`